# Show that if $W$ is a finite dimensional $K$-vector space any linear surjective map $f:W\to W$ is bijective.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that if $W$ is a finite dimensional $K$-vector space any linear surjective map $f:W\to W$ is bijective.

I feel that the rank nullity theorem is needed for this one...

We are given that $f$ is surjective, so we must show that it is also injective, then we have bijectivity. But how would I show $f$ is injective when $f$ is a general mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the rank-nullity theorem, also called the dimensions' theorem:

$$\dim W=\dim\ker T+\dim\text{Im}\,T\stackrel{\text{given}}=\dim\ker T+\dim W\implies\dim\ker T=0$$

Now just use/prove that **any** linear map is injective iff $\;\ker T=\{0\}\;$ .

Comment: Excellent. I don't suppose you could answer my secondary question that I commented on @CameronJWhitehead's answer? I'd really love to know the answer to it!

Comment: A (in fact, **the**) basis of the zero vector space is the empty set $\;\emptyset\;$ , thus its dimension is zero. This may be a little abstract for a beginner, yet it is true. Observe that the only vector in $\;\{0\}\;$ is the zero vector and it **can not** be part of any basis as any set containing it is automatically linearly *dependent*

Comment: Just wanted to say, while the basis of the zero vector space is the empty set this is a $\textit{convention/definition}$. This set doesn't really span the zero vector space, because there is nothing to multiply, so it really is a definition rather than something we can prove. It's one of those sort of arsey definitions mathematicians kinda need so that the nice things (like the rank-nullity theorem, or the dimension formula for the sum of subspaces) remain true. A similar example is the question `what is the product of no numbers?' .

Comment: @CameronJWhitehead Well, it doesn't necessarily is a convention or definition but it may also follow from *another* well-known and widely accepted notion's definition: span. By definition, the space of a set is the *intersecttion* of all subspaces containing that set. Thus, the span of the empty set is the intersection of **all subspaces** (as *every set, and thus every subspace*, axiomatically contain the empty set), and the intersection of *all* subspaces of a vector space is the zero subspace...

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{HINT:}$ A linear map is injective if and only if it has $\ker(f) = \{0\}$, which is true if and only if dim$(\ker f) = 0$, now try using the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up @CameronJWhitehead! This is a problem I came across the other day. If $\ker (f) = {0}$, then how can $\dim (\ker f)=0$? Surely the dimension of the kernel is one, because it contains one element?